# How can I open multiple pinboard bookmarks at once?

Tags: firefox

I've got a variety of tags in [pinboard](https://pinboard.in/) (A bookmarking website not far off from what [delicious](https://del.icio.us/) used to be), and I'd like to be able to open all of a tag's bookmarks in one action (like right clicking a folder of bookmarks in a browser).

Has anyone got a good way to do this? I mostly use Firefox on Windows and Android.

Comment: What is Pinboard? Is it a website?

Comment: Web services are off-topic on SU.  From the pinboard site description, it sounds like it behaves like an app, so this would probably be on-topic on Web Apps.